# grouping data using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having list of objects and on the view I want to display them grouped by ParentName without duplicates in displaying parents name, for example every object MyObject has Id, Name, ParentName

```
MyObject
public int Id {get; set; }
public string Name {get; set; }
public string ParentName {get; set; }
```

On the view I have

```
@model List<MyObject>
```

and I want to display data like this

```
---- PARENT A -----
   ObjectOne Name
   ObjectTwo Name
   ObjectThree Name

 ---- PARENT B -----
   ObjectOne Name
   ObjectTwo Name
   ObjectThree Name
```

so I've tried like this

```
@{ 
  foreach(var mydata in @Model.GroupBy(d=>d.ParentName).Select(g=>g.First()))
  {
     // this returns only one Name per parent, I know this is because g.First() statement, 
     // but I dont know how to select all items instead of this one?
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea I had misread your question; don't know how I came to the orderby stuff. I'm going to lay down.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var mydata in @Model
    .GroupBy(d=>d.ParentName)
    .Select(g=>
         Tuple.Create(
               g.Key,
               g)))
```

(of course you can beauty the code by using a new custom struct instead of this ugly tuple).

Comment: `g.First().ParentName` is equal to `g.Key`

Comment: +1 for both of you for learning me new things (although I understand they are trivial :) ). I'll fix my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `g.ToList()` instead of `g.First()` and also change `Select` to `SelectMany`.

```
@Model.GroupBy(d => d.ParentName).SelectMany(g => g.ToList())
```

BTW, if you are using `MVC`, don't do that in your `View`.You should perform this kind of operations on your `Controller`, and then just pass the results to the `View`.